# Handling onClick and double click

Tags: java, android

I have a messaging app similar to whatsapp where there are messages videos and images in the chat activity. Now I want to implement a **double tap** like feature on this but the problem is I also have a **onclicklistner** attached to my image and video frame that opens up a fullscreenactivity showing the image in fullscreen or playing the video in fullscreen. So on double tap instead of liking the picture or video it simply opens the video or image in the fullscreen mode. Since in messages I don't have a onclick listner attached double tap like works fine. Any ideas on how I can make the double tap like work in case of the videos or images. I am fairly new to android development using Java. So any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> *HI, I think the approach to take depends on the future of your app, using LongClick is kinda good but what if you want to achieve a zoom like onLongClick?*
>
> > What I did below is that I created a subclass that extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener and then in my GestureTest class, I an ontouchListener and return the gesture instance created before, finally I parse the listener to the button that has to perform the clicks, it can be any View object.
> >     Finally, I used the TextView I created to display/monitor my actions.
>
> **GestureDetector like below:**

```
public class GestureTest extends AppCompatActivity{

    private Button btn;
    private TextView actions;
    private GestureDetector mDetector;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gesture_test);

        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
        actions = findViewById(R.id.action);

        mDetector = new GestureDetector(this, new SampleGestureListener());
        View.OnTouchListener touchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                return mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };

        btn.setOnTouchListener(touchListener);
    }

    public class SampleGestureListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener{

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
                Log.e("EVENT","BUTTON PRESSED DOWN, NOT YET RELEASED WILL TRIGGER ONLONG-PRESS");

                // don't return false here or else none of the other
                // gestures will work
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent e) {
                Log.e("EVENT", "SINGLE CLICK EVENT");
                actions.setText("THIS CLICK IS FOR IMAGE OR VIDEO TO OPEN ?");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                Log.e("EVENT", "LONG PRESSED");
                actions.setText("THIS IS ZOOM LIKE NOT DOUBLE CLICK!!!");
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                Log.e("EVENT", "DOUBLE CLICKED HAPPENED");
                actions.setText("THIS CLICK IS TO LIKE IMAGE OR VIDEO ?");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2,
                                    float distanceX, float distanceY) {
                Log.e("EVENT", "SCROLLING");
                actions.setText("YOU\" Scrolling on many images...");
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent event1, MotionEvent event2,
                                   float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                Log.e("EVENT", "FLINGED");
                actions.setText("THIS IS TINDER FLING LIKE ?");
                return true;
            }
        }
}
```

> > **AND BELOW IS MY `activity_gesture_test.xml` FOR TESTING:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btn"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

> **GoodLuck Coding.**

Comment: Very comprehensive solution although in my case I could not get it to work like I wanted to but nonetheless very elegant solution. Thank you.

Comment: Any reason why you couldn't ?
Also, I will like you to share the Solution that works for you.

Comment: In my handlevideo and handleimage functions I take likeiconview as a parameter and I can toggle the like view from within the function. But in the solution you provided since single click or double click is being triggered in a separate class i.e. simplegesture class I need to pass the reference to the like view to a constructor in that class. But the way my handlevideo function is called is that the most recent video shared will be passed last to the handlevideo function. And in this case I need to pass the likeicon reference to the simplegesturelistner.

Comment: Now no matter what it will always have the refence to the like icon view of the last video/image. So no matter on which image or video I click the like icon of the last video/image is being toggled.There is no problem with your solution its just the way my function is written that its a limitation and solution that @Mehrdad provided works fine for me because there is no need to pass the like view and I can handle the likeview from within the function.

Answer (score 1):

try this for double click:

```
int i = 0;
btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    i++;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            i = 0;
        }
    };
    if (i == 1) {
        //Single click
        handler.postDelayed(r, 250);
    } else if (i == 2) {
        //Double click
        i = 0;
        ShowDailog();
    }


}
});
```

and for click listener:

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It is generally accepted to use long tap instead of double click in android apps. Try this:

```
yourView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                //do Your stuff here

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Comment: Since its a messaging app so long tap is used for different purpose i.e. on long tap the message is selected and allows user to forward that message or archieve it and etc you get the gist. Just like in whatsapp so longClick is already being used so its not an option for liking the message.